# Sanov-type finite-sample bound on $KL(P\|\hat{P}_n)$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration, large-deviations

Let $P$ be a distribution on an alphabet of size $k$ and let $\hat{P}_n$ be an empirical version of $P$ via $n$ i.i.d samples $a_1,\ldots,a_n \sim P$, i.e $\hat{P}_n := (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{a_i}$.

## Question

Does there exist a **non-asymptotic** bound of the form $\text{Proba}(KL(P \|\hat{P}_n) \ge \epsilon) \le (n + 1)^ke^{-\epsilon n}$ ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- this is exactly Sanov's theorem, no? I find it as Theorem 11.4.1 of Cover and Thomas, and earlier in that chapter. (I guess some places only mention the asymptotic version?)

Comment: @usul Thanks for the input. (1) Part of my frustration is that I haven't seen any **non-asymptotic** version of the theorem anywhere. So I'd be more than appreciate any good reference on the subject. (2) I really mean $KL(P\|\hat{P}_n)$. Just to be clear, $KL(p\|q) := \int \log(\frac{dp}{dq})dp$ is $p \ll q$, and $KL(p\|q) := \infty$ otherwise.

Comment: Indeed a **non-asymptotic** inequality for $Proba(KL(\hat{P}_n\|P) \ge \epsilon)$ is given and proven in Theorem 11.2.1 of Cover and Thomas http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~cgong821/Wiley.Interscience.Elements.of.Information.Theory.Jul.2006.eBook-DDU.pdf.

Comment: Still I'm interested in $KL(P\|\hat{P}_n)$.

Comment: Ah great, thanks. OK, this is going to be really problematic because if you don't sample some $x$, then $\hat{P}(x) = 0$ and your KL-divergence is infinite, but $P$ can put arbitrarily small probability on some $x$ requiring arbitrarily many samples to avoid this...(right?)

Comment: Sure. You may assume $\kappa := \min_a P(a) / \max_a P(a) > 0$, and I don't mind a bound which depends very badly on this "condition number"  $\kappa$.